# FTP script not working

Tags: linux, ftp

I have an FTP script running on Linux and it is failing. Here is the script:

```
/usr/bin/ftp -v -i -n my.ftp.server << cmd
user ftpuser password 
binary 
ls 
<some other commands here>
quit cmd
```

It returns an error:

```
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection 
Not connected.
```

The weird thing here is that if I just typed this in the command line:
/usr/bin/ftp my.ftp.server
It asks for a username and password and after I supplied them, I was able to connect!

In ftp> I type ls and I can see the files from the FTP server. 
What is wrong with my script?

And also, I don't have putty access to the FTP server so I can't see the logs from there. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a correct ftp linux script.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.server.com'
USER='user'
PASSWD='pw'
FILE='file.txt' #sample file to upload

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE #sample command
#some other commands here
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: I tested your script and it worked fine in our dev setup but it still failed in our production setup. I noticed that all lines executed after the 1st line (ftp -n $host <<end_script) returned an error. 421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection. It won't even accept the username and password supplied